# Warning: Running "compass:server" (compass) task

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, yo

```
D:\Projects\mallspk>grunt serve
Running "serve" task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task
>> 0 paths cleaned.

Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task

Running "wiredep:test" (wiredep) task

Running "wiredep:sass" (wiredep) task

Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task
    Warning: Running "compass:server" (compass) task
Warning: Command failed: 'compass.bat' is not recognized as an internal or exter
nal command,
    operable program or batch file.
     Use --force to continue.
```

I have install the `Yo angular` and runs the followings commands:

```
npm install grunt --save-dev
npm install -g grunt-contrib-compass 
npm install -g compass
npm install
bower install
npm install  grunt-google-cdn
```

and when i run the command `grunt serve` i have got this error. i have latest node and npm install with latest grunt and yo.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I had ruby install @squiroid. I forget to run `gem install compass`. That worked for me.

Comment: this is not the thank you answer this the solution for my problem. and i have answer my question so anyone who are facing this problem will found the correct solution.

Comment: I had to run `sudo apt-get install ruby-compass` first

Answer (score 16):

I've the same problem in ubuntu and I did this to solve my problem :

1. `sudo apt-get install ruby`
2. `sudo apt-get install ruby-compass`
3. `sudo gem install compass`

after that `grunt serve`  works

Comment: I had installed ruby, and had installed compass gem, but for some reason I had to install apt-get ruby-compass still, as suggested here. Thanks!

Comment: I use this solution, It's needed to install ruby-compass with apt, if not in ubuntu doesnt work. THANKS !!!

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem I installed compass gem on my desktop and it is resolved.

If you're on OS X or Linux you probably already have Ruby installed; test with ruby -v in your terminal. When you've confirmed you have Ruby installed, run gem update --system && gem install compass to install Compass and Sass.

For windows you can download [ruby](http://rubyinstaller.org/) and then install compass.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: You should actually probably not use the installed version of ruby on your system, if you're on Ubuntu. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37720892/you-dont-have-write-permissions-for-the-var-lib-gems-2-3-0-directory/37956249

Answer (score 7):

I searched and searched ... until finally I got the answer to this problem.
In my case it happened when I was creating a new angularjs application with yeomen.

**This answer is specific to windows users**

Step 1: Install ruby
http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

Step 2 : download rubygems 
Link : https://rubygems.org/rubygems/rubygems-2.6.8.zip

Step 3 : unzip rubygems-2.6.8.zip

Step 4 : open powershell (terminal/command line) to the rubygems-2.6.8 folder path.(location of the folder eg. c:\folder\folder)

Step 5 : in the powershell terminal run these commands

```
> ruby setup.rb

> gem install compass
```

enjoy!

Comment: Thanks this is great.  Bad part is i'm not even using ruby.  NET web api with angular front end.

Comment: me too. Trust me it works. The ruby is so that the css pre-compiler sass/or less can run. At Least when running locally

Comment: works perfectly. Although I have to open command prompt with ruby. Know a way to open ConEmu with ruby? because ruby didn't install globally on my system. So I can't just use it anywhere. Don't know why.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem

"yo angular" with sass option will use the compass, which is a ruby gem.

Install the ruby, and the compass

In windows system we also need to set the path of ruby. Add the ruby/bin to path

Then "grunt serve" works!

Comment: Thanks for this. Everything else I read just said to update compass, and no other Windows specific solutions mentioned ruby needed to be added to the path.

Comment: Adding .RB and .RBW to the environement Variable Value list as %PATHEXT%;.RB;.RBW and click OK. checkout http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_installation_windows.htm

Answer (score 1):

I have those problems too, I found a temporary fix by setting the source maps to false.

```
server: {
        options: {
          sourcemap: false <--
        }
      }
```

after that, it works like charm.

Answer (score 1):

From the document of [grunt-contrib-compass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-compass), that says:

> "This task requires you to have Ruby, Sass, and Compass >=1.0.1 installed"
>   and 
>   "When you've confirmed you have Ruby installed, run gem update --system && gem install compass to install Compass and Sass."

I followed this instruction and fixed the warning.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same strange feeling about Ruby when using node+express+Angluar, run "yo angular xyz", but use **gulp** instead of grunt.