# You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/2.3.0 directory

Tags: rubygems, bundler

I have ruby installed on my ubuntu 16.04.

```
$which ruby  

/usr/bin/ruby

$ruby -v 

ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

$gem install bundler 

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/2.3.0 directory.
```

Comment: You can try to install RVM and install a newer version of ruby like 2.3.3

Comment: For comment 3: the package "python-software-properties" is not available you should replace for software-properties-common

Comment: The RVM option, and imho even better&simple [install as a pure “user-install”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18294746/444255) (as opposed to a global, rights-demanding one) might be a much better thing to, than tinkering with rights!

Comment: I wish this stream explained why this OP had this problem and why they should abandon a version of Ruby in favor of both Ruby and a multiple installation manager (RVM or RBEVN). I'm unable to tell for sure whether the advice here is based solely on personal preference. I hope there's more behind this advice.

Comment: `sudo gem install bundler` ?

Comment: Sometimes this issue is due to shell user. Below command worked for me.
`/bin/bash --login`

Comment: Coming back to this question 6 years later, and working with ruby v 2.7 (installed with apt), I ran into this same error while installing minitest gem, however despite that, a .gem directory got created under $HOME and it had minitest in it... and it works. What sorcery is this

Answer (score 251, accepted):

You first need to uninstall the ruby installed by Ubuntu with something like `sudo apt-get remove ruby`.

Then reinstall ruby using [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#readme) and [ruby-build](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build) according to their docs:

```
cd $HOME
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libffi-dev

git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL

git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL

rbenv install 2.3.1
rbenv global 2.3.1
ruby -v
```

The last step is to install Bundler:

```
gem install bundler
rbenv rehash
```

Comment: Instruction how to install ruby (on rails) is here https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04

Comment: I'm kind of reticent to do the uninstall, since it requires uninstalling dependent programs too (`vim-gnome` for example). I guess I would prefer to know _why_ in the first place it needs to write in `/var/lib/...` for a user install... Did I do a `sudo gem install` when not needed?

Comment: I agree with @AntonSkovorodko , it'd be nice if the answer could justify the uninstall of Ruby

Comment: Just be careful when uninstalling Ruby in Cinnamon environment (happened in Linux Mint 18.2), after reboot I could not run system in graphic mode. When this happens to you, go to to CLI via `Ctrl+Alt+F1` and run following commands (uninstalls and installs Cinnamon again):

`sudo apt purge cinnamon && sudo apt install cinnamon`

Comment: as this answer ages, you'll probably want to know what the latest available are: `rbenv install -l` for a list all available versions then `rbenv install 2.5.1` for the 2.5.1 version or whatever you'd like.

Comment: apt-get is not found in my Mac. I don't know what can I do now

Comment: `E: Package 'python-software-properties' has no installation candidate`

Comment: For those getting `Package 'python-software-properties' has no installation candidate`, you can install it by running: 
`sudo apt-get install software-properties-common`

Comment: Following onto what @PaulSturm stated, we're up to 2.7 now.  `rbenv install 2.7.1`

Comment: thank you so much, I have been struggling with different ways to install for half an hour

Comment: On Ubuntu 18 the flow of these comands seems to have changed somewhat.
sudo apt remove ruby-all-dev
sudo apt install rbenv
rbenv init
add line specified in rbenv init to bash rc with nano ~/.bashrc paste output from previous command at the bottom.
source ~/.bashrc
mkdir -p "$(rbenv root)"/plugins
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git "$(rbenv root)"/plugins/ruby-build
curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/main/bin/rbenv-doctor | bash
rbenv install 3.0.2

Comment: You could add the export PATHs to `~/.profile` to accommodate other shells, or if you're using zsh, like me change `~/.bashrc` to either `~/.zshrc` or `~/.zprofile`.

Comment: These days I would recommend asdf over language specific toolings: https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-ruby
Otherwise you end up installing rbenv for Ruby, NVM/Volta for JavaScript, pyenv for Python etc. etc. with a specific workflow for each

Comment: fish users should check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73835179/12911698

Comment: got error at `rbenv install 2.3.1` `make: *** [uncommon.mk:442: rdoc] Error 1`

Comment: virttual environments should be avoided as a non-permanent solution.  Installs should be for all users.

Answer (score 129):

If you want to use the distribution Ruby instead of rb-env/rvm, you can set up a `GEM_HOME` for your current user. Start by creating a directory to store the Ruby gems for *your* user:

```
$ mkdir ~/.ruby
```

Then update your shell to use that directory for `GEM_HOME` and to update your `PATH` variable to include the Ruby gem bin directory.

```
$ echo 'export GEM_HOME=~/.ruby/' >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo 'export PATH="$PATH:~/.ruby/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

(That last line will reload the environment variables in your current shell.)

Now you should be able to install Ruby gems under your user using the `gem` command. I was able to get this working with Ruby 2.5.1 under Ubuntu 18.04. If you are using a shell that is not Bash, then you will need to edit the startup script for that shell instead of `bashrc`.

Comment: I did this, then got an error about "can't find header files for ruby", then I read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4502672/2245874 , and didn't follow all of it but did do sudo apt install ruby-gems, and then it worked for me.

Comment: I believe @robm meant ruby-dev not ruby-gems

Comment: This is probably more appropriate for ruby users that don't need to develop against multiple versions.

Comment: You decribed a really good Linux way to fix my ruby install without any additional tools, just good old bash :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Definitely a clear and laconic solution! But instead of using `~/.bashrc` file, I’d suggest writing to the `~/.profile` one that will allow using not only Bash-specific scripts and terminals (that is especially actual if you have to use a `/bin/sh` script). The `~/.bashrc` is exactly for tuning Bash, not all the shell or environment.

Comment: fish users should check this answer stackoverflow.com/a/73835179/12911698

Answer (score 49):

***(January 2019) To install Ruby using the Rbenv script, follow these steps:***

***1. First, update the packages index and install the packages required
for the ruby-build tool to build Ruby from source:***

```
sudo apt-get remove ruby
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git curl libssl-dev libreadline-dev zlib1g-dev autoconf bison build-essential libyaml-dev libreadline-dev libncurses5-dev libffi-dev libgdbm-dev
```

***2. Next, run the following curl command to install both rbenv and
ruby-build:***

```
curl -sL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/main/bin/rbenv-installer | bash -
```

***3. Add $HOME/.rbenv/bin to the system PATH.***

**If you are using Bash, run:**

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

**If you are using Zsh run:**

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
```

***4. Install the latest stable version of Ruby and set it as a default
version with:***

```
rbenv install 2.5.1
rbenv global 2.5.1
```

> To list all available Ruby versions you can use: `rbenv install -l`

***5. Verify that Ruby was properly installed by printing out the version
number:***

```
ruby -v

# Output
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]
```

SOURCE: [How To Install Ruby on Ubuntu 18.04](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-ruby-on-ubuntu-18-04/)

***EDIT: Install rubygems:***

```
sudo apt-get install rubygems
```

Comment: this is great! nice and succinct. I followed it exactly (except the `.zshrc` changes that I did by hand) and it worked perfectly. In the same way you added how to install `rubygems`, I'd suggest maybe adding how to later update the installed ruby version (I'm guessing you just run the `rbenv install` and `rbenv global` commands again and maybe `rbenv uninstall` to prune outdated versions)

Comment: This is amazing! Works perfectly on Ubuntu 18.04 WSL.

Comment: This is more elegant answer.

Comment: Why should I install `rubygems` package separately. Isn't this shipped out with `ruby`?

Answer (score 31):

Ubuntu 20.04:

### Option 1 - set up a gem installation directory for your user account

For bash (for zsh, we would use `.zshrc` of course)

```
echo '# Install Ruby Gems to ~/gems' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export GEM_HOME="$HOME/gems"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/gems/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

### Option 2 - use snap

Uninstall the apt-version (`ruby-full`) and reinstall it with `snap`

```sh
sudo apt-get remove ruby
sudo snap install ruby --classic
```

Comment: I am following option 2.

Comment: Option 2 doesn't work in WSL, option 1 does.

Answer (score 28):

Rather than changing owners, which might lock out other local users, or –some day– your own ruby server/deployment-things... running under a different user...

I would rather simply extend rights of that particular folder to... well, everybody:

```
cd /var/lib
sudo chmod -R a+w gems/
```

(I did encounter your error as well. So this is fairly verified.)

Comment: I also needed to address /usr/local/bin folder, but this solution did work: "ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/local/bin directory."

Comment: Much better than bashrc crap,  or virtual environments, this is a global solution.

Answer (score 10):

I encountered the same error in GitHub Actions. Adding `sudo` solved the issue.

```
sudo gem install bundler
```

Comment: You should never install these frameworks using `sudo`.

Answer (score 9):

Try using `chown -R` on the `var/lib/gems` directory, assigning ownership to the user [`rubyusername`] in this example, the user that will be installing and developing with gems.

```
 # chown -R rubyusername:rubyusername /var/lib/gems
```

This **recursively** changes everything under the *gems* directory.  For extra security on multi-user systems, you can also create a group, rather than chowning the individual rubyusername, and add users to that group.

Comment: It can solve that problem, but another issue pops up:
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/local/bin directory
; so I guess something else is wrong instead of the permission.

Comment: I get other errors later
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Answer (score 4):

Building on derek's answer above, it is generally not recommended to use the system provided Ruby instance for your own development work, as system tools might depend on the particular version or location of the Ruby install. Similar to [this answer for Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14607772/5163325), you will want to follow derek's instructions on using something like rbenv ([RVM](https://rvm.io/) is a similar alternative) to install your own Ruby instance.

However, there is no need to uninstall the system version of Ruby, the rbenv installation instructions provide a mechanism to make sure that the instance of Ruby available in your shell is the rbenv instance, not the system instance. This is the

```
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

line in derek's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using the **snap version** of Ruby solved the problem for me:

- Remove the default version:
  `sudo apt-get remove ruby`
- Install another one using snap:
  `sudo snap install ruby --classic`
- You can now run `gem install bundler`

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling Compass worked for me.. It's a magic!

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin compass
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running `rbenv rehash` before installing bundler?

I ran into this using WSL2 running Ubuntu 20.04.

I installed rbenv and ruby-build through GitHub and proceeded to install ruby 3.0.1 and set that as the global version.

```
➜  ~ rbenv install 3.0.1
Downloading ruby-3.0.1.tar.gz...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/3.0/ruby-3.0.1.tar.gz
Installing ruby-3.0.1...
Installed ruby-3.0.1 to /home/kayla/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1
➜  ~ rbenv global 3.0.1
➜  ~ ruby -v
ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
➜  ~ gem install bundler
Fetching bundler-2.2.20.gem
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/2.7.0 directory.
```

My ruby was installed in the same location:

```
➜  ~ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

Instead of re-installing rbenv and ruby-build entirely, all I needed to do was rehash before installing bundler:

```
➜  ~ rbenv rehash
➜  ~ gem install bundler
Fetching bundler-2.2.20.gem
Successfully installed bundler-2.2.20
Parsing documentation for bundler-2.2.20
Installing ri documentation for bundler-2.2.20
Done installing documentation for bundler after 3 seconds
1 gem installed
```

One clue that might've hinted to this earlier, was that the return value for `ruby -v` before I rehashed was ruby 2.7.0, not 3.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

For Fish Shell users:

### To set the environment variable

in your `~/.config/fish/config.fish` put :

```
set -gx PATH $HOME/.rbenv/bin $PATH
set -gx PATH $HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin $PATH
```

Those are the equivalent fish commands for:

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

### Init the `rbevn` function

also in your `~/.config/fish/config.fish` put:

```
rbenv init - | source
```

this is the fish equivalent to

```
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

### Source your configs

```
source ~/.config/fish/config.fish
```

Answer (score -1):

You should install brew

```
curl -fsSL -o install.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh
/bin/bash install.sh
brew install chruby ruby-install
brew install cocoapods
brew upgrade cocoapods
```

Xcode Command Line Tools is needed, if it is not installed, run this command: `sudo xcode-select --install`.

Comment: the question was asked for Ubuntu...  this answer is applicable for MAC OS only.