# Rails: The program 'rails' is currently not installed on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I installed rvm ruby and gem. 
When I used gem to install rails, it's like this:

```
woyuxuxu123@ubuntu:~$ sudo gem install rails
[sudo] password for woyuxuxu123: 
Successfully installed rails-5.1.4
Parsing documentation for rails-5.1.4
Done installing documentation for rails after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

But when I enter rails -v, I got:

```
woyuxuxu123@ubuntu:~$ rails -v
The program 'rails' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install ruby-railties
```

I tried some solutions, but did not work for me, such as

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Someone mentioned the path. Here is how it looks

```
RubyGems Environment:
EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin

woyuxuxu123@ubuntu:~$ echo $PATH
/home/woyuxuxu123/bin:/home/woyuxuxu123/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/woyuxuxu123/.rvm/bin:/home/woyuxuxu123/.rvm/bin
```

What should I do?

Comment: Somebody helps please. It's very urgent!

Comment: did you try `gem install rails` without `sudo`?

Comment: @djothefou I tried and I got a "You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/2.3.0 directory."

Comment: DONT use sudo !! You need to restart your terminal, close it and open it again

Comment: @MrYoshiji It said I do not have write permissions without sudo

Comment: @MrYoshiji I did what you said but it's still the same

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37720892/you-dont-have-write-permissions-for-the-var-lib-gems-2-3-0-directory , instead of rbenv try to remove and install again according of rvm docs

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue for **Rails 5.2** and **Ubuntu 18.04**. I had an already setup server with Ruby and Rails installed, but I couldn't access them.

The error output was:

> The program 'rails' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
>   sudo apt install ruby-railties

The issue is simply caused by the rails executable not being globally accessible by programs.

**Here's how I solved it**

**Note:** If you are working on a production server, endeavour to make a backup of your database before trying out the solution below to avoid data loss.

For my case, my version manager was **rbenv** and not **rvm**

Re-install **rbenv** itself. Clone the **rbenv** repository from GitHub into the directory ~/.rbenv:

`git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv`

Next, add `~/.rbenv/bin` to your `$PATH` so that you can use the rbenv command line utility. Do this by altering your ~/.bashrc file so that it affects future login sessions:

`echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc`

Then add the command eval "$(rbenv init -)" to your ~/.bashrc file so rbenv loads automatically:

`echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc`

Next, apply the changes you made to your ~/.bashrc file to your current shell session:

`source ~/.bashrc`

Verify that **rbenv** is set up properly by using the type command, which will display more information about the **rbenv** command:

`type rbenv`

Your terminal window will display the following:

```
rbenv is a function
rbenv ()
{
    local command;
    command="${1:-}";
    if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
        shift;
    fi;
    case "$command" in
        rehash | shell)
            eval "$(rbenv "sh-$command" "$@")"
        ;;
        *)
            command rbenv "$command" "$@"
        ;;
    esac
}
```

If everything worked right, running the command below will display the versions of **Ruby** and **Rails** previously installed on your machine:

```
ruby -v
rails -v
```

Else, run a fresh installation of **Ruby** and **Rails** on your machine.

That's all

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

Probably you forgot to add rvm script to your .bash_profile:

`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`

Try running `rvm repair all` and then restart your terminal.

Comment: Actually I had this line in my .bash_profile. I tried rvm repair all and restarted my terminal, but it does not work.

Comment: @XINDILI Did you run `rvm use <installed_ruby_version> --default` before installing rails gem? What is your output of `which gem` command in terminal?

Comment: I reinstalled everything and runned rvm use <installed_ruby_version> --default. Now it works. Thank you so much

Comment: But I run bash --login in order to run rvm use. So now every time I open the console, I have to run bash --login. And then I can use rails. That's a problem

Comment: @XINDILI Well, you need to use "--login" option to run shell interactively. Try to add `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` to .bashrc or .profile instead of .bash_profile.

Comment: @XINDILI Also look here https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files