# GitHub action fails to install gem

Tags: ruby, github-actions

I have the following GitHub action:

```
name: Rubocop
on: push

jobs:
  check:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Install Rubocop
        run: gem install rubocop
      - name: Rubocop
        run: rubocop
```

When this action runs, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/2.5.0 directory.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Which command fails? Have you tried to prefix your command with `sudo`?

Comment: `gem install rubocop`, and no I have not tried to prefix it with `sudo`.

Answer (score 7):

Use the following as per the [official GitHub Actions docs](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/guides/building-and-testing-ruby#linting-your-code):

```yaml
name: Linting

on: [push]

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
      with:
        ruby-version: 2.6
    - run: bundle install
    - name: Rubocop
      run: rubocop
```

or if you don't have a `gemfile`:

```yaml
name: Linting

on: [push]

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
      with:
        ruby-version: 2.6
    - run: gem install rubocop
    - name: Rubocop
      run: rubocop
```

`sudo gem install rubocop` is another option as described in [You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/2.3.0 directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37720892/you-dont-have-write-permissions-for-the-var-lib-gems-2-3-0-directory/60395251#60395251)

Comment: The thing I was missing was `- uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1`, after doing that, my permissions issues were resolved

Answer (score 0):

Consider using docker. If your repo is to be containerized and your Action is a test it would be better to run the test in the same docker image environment rather than some GitHub's Ubuntu:

```
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - run: docker run -v $(pwd):/checkout ruby:alpine sh -c "cd checkout && gem install bundler && bundle install && bundle exec ruby test.rb"
```