# Make sure that `gem install byebug -v '11.1.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to install the byebug gem for ruby on visual studio code and every time I try to use bundle install to install it, it gives me this error:

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen -
/home/ja12tk/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/byebug-11.1.3/CHANGELOG.md
An error occurred while installing byebug (11.1.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install byebug -v '11.1.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds
before bundling.
```

This is what the Gemfile says:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "byebug"
gem "rspec", "~> 3.2.0"
```

Along with the Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    byebug (11.1.3)
    diff-lcs (1.4.4)
    rspec (3.2.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.2.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.2.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.2.0)
    rspec-core (3.2.3)
      rspec-support (~> 3.2.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.2.1)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.2.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.2.1)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.2.0)
    rspec-support (3.2.2)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  byebug
  rspec (~> 3.2.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   2.1.4
```

I have even tried using "gem install byebug" and it give me this error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/2.7.0 directory.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37720892/you-dont-have-write-permissions-for-the-var-lib-gems-2-3-0-directory

Answer (score 0):

I had run into the same problem, but this is how I solved it

I ran

- **sudo apt-get install ruby-dev** on the root terminal
- then, **bundle install** under required Gemfile directory

That's all