# Always the same version of gem is installing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to make new `ruby on rails` project with:

```
rails new . --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

But at the end of execution of this command I got:

```
         run  bundle install
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.2.6) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
      bundler (< 2.0, >= 1.3.0)

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (2.2.27)

Your bundle requires a different version of Bundler than the one you're running.
Install the necessary version with `gem install bundler:2.0.0.pre.3` and rerun bundler using `bundle _2.0.0.pre.3_ install`
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.............
Resolving dependencies...
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
Traceback (most recent call last):
    13: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    12: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    11: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.27/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.27/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:88:in `silence'
     9: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.27/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:136:in `with_level'
     8: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.27/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
     7: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.27/lib/bundler.rb:149:in `setup'
     6: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.27/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:18:in `setup'
     5: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.27/lib/bundler/definition.rb:234:in `specs_for'
     4: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.27/lib/bundler/definition.rb:483:in `materialize'
     3: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.27/lib/bundler/definition.rb:262:in `resolve'
     2: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.27/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:23:in `resolve'
     1: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.27/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:46:in `start'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.27/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:59:in `rescue in start': Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler": (Bundler::VersionConflict)
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.2.6) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
      bundler (< 2.0, >= 1.3.0)

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (2.2.27)

Your bundle requires a different version of Bundler than the one you're running.
Install the necessary version with `gem install bundler:1.11.2` and rerun bundler using `spring _1.11.2_ binstub --all`
```

After that I removed ruby, so that with commands `ruby -v` I got:

```
bash: /home/iva/.rbenv/shims/ruby: No such file or directory
```

Then I installed again ruby and installed gem with `gem install bundler:1.11.2`. But after this installation with checking versions of ruby and gem I got:

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]
gem -v
2.7.6
```

I don't know how is this `2.7.6` version of gem when I gave command with version `1.11.2`?
So it seems like some circle, and I don`t know how to get out of it. I am installing ruby, it requires older version of gem, but with any command newest version of gem is always installing at my computer. What should I do in this situation?

=============================================================
Response for this commands are:

```
rbenv versions
* 2.5.1 (set by /home/iva/.rbenv/version)
echo $PATH
/home/iva/.rbenv/shims:/home/iva/.rbenv/bin:/home/iva/.rbenv/shims:/home/iva/.rbenv/bin:/home/iva/.rbenv/shims:/home/iva/.rbenv/bin:/home/iva/.rbenv/shims:/home/iva/.rbenv/bin:/home/iva/.rbenv/shims:/home/iva/.rbenv/bin:/home/iva/.rbenv/shims:/home/iva/.rbenv/bin:/home/iva/bin:/home/iva/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/iva/.rvm/bin:/home/iva/.rvm/bin:/home/iva/.rvm/bin:/home/iva/.rvm/bin:/home/iva/.rvm/bin
```

Comment: How did you reinstalled Ruby ? Can you post the output of `rbenv versions` and `echo $PATH` please ?

Comment: I added response for `rbenv versions` and `echo $PATH` commands in my question. I am reinstalling ruby with tutorial from there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37720892/you-dont-have-write-permissions-for-the-var-lib-gems-2-3-0-directory (third answer with 39 ups: (January 2019) To install Ruby using the Rbenv script, follow these steps:)

Answer (score 2):

1. Why are you creating a new rails project **with rails version `4.2.6`**?? Is this really intentional?! Rails 4.2.6 was [released](https://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2016/3/11/Rails-4-2-6-and-4-1-15-have-been-released/) on March 11, 2016. It is fairly old/outdated, and no longer supported. The [latest version of rails](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions/6.1.4.1) is `6.1.4.1`.
2. The error message said that your version of `bundler` is incompatible with the version of `rails`. There is nothing in that error to suggest you needed to reinstall ruby, but I guess it didn't do any harm...
3. `gem` and `bundler` are different things. To check the version of `bundler`, run: `bundle -v`, not `gem -v`. You should hopefully see `1.11.2` as you expected.

In short:

- I don't see anything wrong with your current setup. If you reinstall `rails v4.2.6`, then run `rails new`, I'd expect it to work. Your confusion seems to be between comparing versions of different things (namely `ruby`, `gem` and `bundler`).
- This confusion would have been avoided if you'd just installed the latest version of everything. I'm not clear why you're trying to create a new rails project with such an old version. Maybe you've got a good reason for that decision, and that's fine; but if not, then just use the latest versions.